# What is the point of mvc Label helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I understand that the actionlink uses the route tables to display the corrert link, but what advantage does the Html.Label helper offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label helper doesn't do a whole lot. Its function is to encapsulate a small bit of markup so you don't have to write the HTML by hand each time. It also provides **intellisense**. This is helpful when you change a value in your model, then you don't have to go back and edit your view. Ideally, your label text and target should be driven from your `ViewModel` using `LabelFor` and not defined in your HTML.

If you look at the source code for the `Label` helper, it does the following:

```
//Create a new <label> element
TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("label");
//Add the attribute "for" with the id value of the target <input>
tag.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName)));
//Set the label text <label>My Text</label>
tag.SetInnerText(resolvedLabelText);
//Merge any attributes specified in the htmlAttributes arguement (ex: class="style")
tag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes, replaceExisting: true);
//Write the output rendering, this is not a self closing tag </label>
return tag.ToMvcHtmlString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
```

Note: I referenced LabelFor here instead of Label. However, the LabelFor helper actually calls the Label helper internally. The LabelFor helper is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Just read this from an mvc book

"Finally, it’s worth noting that these HTML helper methods automatically HTML-encode the field values
that they render. That’s very important; otherwise, you’d have no end of XSS vulnerabilities laced
throughout your application."

Pro
ASP.NET MVC 2
Framework

Steven Sanderson

Comment: Simply using HtmlHelpers is not going to save you from XSS, especially the Label helper.

Answer (score 0):

`Html.Label` and `Html.LabelFor` are wrappers around the [HTML label](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label) tag.  One of the core "hidden" features of this tag is that, if it's associated with an input control, you can set focus to the associated control by clicking on the label.  This isn't as big a deal for textboxes and things like that, but using it with your checkboxes and radio buttons will be a significant usability boost for your users - clicking the label has the same effect as clicking inside the control itself.

Comment: Thanks, but thats just an explanation of the label tag, I w\anted to know the advantages of generatign with Html.Label and Html.LabelFor